# Does packaging python apps into deb inhibits usage of virtual environments?

Tags: python, linux, debian, python-3.7, python-venv

I'm currently trying to find a way to setup an application written in python to our production hosts. I currently use Debian packages apt repository so I tend to package the application into a deb package.

The [stdeb](https://pypi.org/project/stdeb/) tool allows me to do so and I successfully created a deb package using the following `setup.py`:

```
import setuptools

ld = "Some long description"

setuptools.setup(
        name = "my_fancy_app",
        version="0.0.1",
        author="Me Myself",
        author_email="me@my.self",
        description="Some description",
        long_description=ld,
        packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
        entry_points={
            'console_scripts': [ 'hlpth = my_fancy_app.__main__:main' ]
        },
        classifiers=[
            "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.7",
            "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
            "Operating System :: OS Independent",
        ],
        python_requires='>=3.7'
)
```

The problem I see is that the paths in the Debian package are already specified to point to system `site-packages`. Here is it

```
$ dpkg -c deb_dist/python3-my-fancy-app_0.0.1-1_all.deb                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
-rw-r--r-- root/root         1 2019-11-27 15:22 ./usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/my_fancy_app/__init__.py                                                                                                                               
-rw-r--r-- root/root        78 2019-11-27 15:23 ./usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/my_fancy_app/__main__.py                                                                                                                               
//...other entries omitted
```

From what I see now such `deb` packaging insists on setting up the package into the "core" `site-packages`. Is there a way to work-around this using Debian packages and allow the app to be able to install into a virtual environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python virtual environments are managed using Python's packaging tools (primarily `pip`, but there are alternatives).

By packaging something up into a Debian package, you've moved it into a format that isn't compatible with Python's tooling, and of course the Debian packaging tools don't know anything about Python virtual environments.

If you want to use your app in a virtual environment, just package it up as a Python package. There's no reason to build a `.deb` package for this use case.